# Cassandra - alter Keyspace without downtime

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm coming from a relational databases background. In PostgreSQL or MySQL if we do any alter statement it'll lock the entire table.

I have a Cassandra cluster(3 nodes) that has `SimpleStretegy` for all the keyspaces. One keyspace has 4 tables and each table has 500GB data.

So if I alter the keyspace to change the strategy, is there any lock or block?

Comment: it'll not lock but remember to run **repair** after alter

Comment: Right now it doesn't have any additional data center, but i'll add a new one. So still I need to run the repair?

Comment: after alter you need to run repair.

Answer (score 1):

The change itself is fast, keyspace in Cassandra is not the physical object, it's just a metadata.  But when you change replication, you need to run repair operation as per [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsChangeKSStrategy.html):

> Simply altering the keyspace may lead to faulty data replication.

If you have one datacenter, then you may not get this problem, but it still better to run the repair.

Comment: I'll add one more data center after this alter command, so I  need to run the repair after the alter command right?

Comment: After ALTER you need to do repair anyway.  If you add new DC after repair, you will need to follow another procedure, because replication will not replicate your existing data automatically, only new changes will go there. See documentation for steps: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html